# SQL - delete row if another table exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete a row from a table if another table doesn't exist. I've tried using the following statement

```
 IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'user3project3'))
 BEGIN
     DELETE FROM user1table WHERE id=3
 END
```

However I get the following error:

```
 Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin with XAMPP, if that matters.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is happening when you try:  IF (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'user3project3') < 1) BEGIN ... END

Comment: @ErayBalkanli and topicstarter, MySQL does not support SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax.. This kind off syntax is possible in MSSQL as plain SQL in MySQL this kind off SQL is only valid in stored procedures/functions or triggers.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IF` statement is only allowed in programming blocks, which in practice means in stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

You *could* express this logic in a single query:

```
DELETE FROM user1table
    WHERE id = 3 AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'user3project3');
```

That said, you have a very questionable data model if you are storing a separate table for each user.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Do you by any change also know how I would go about doing this for an INSERT statement. As in INSERT some values into a table IF some condition?

Comment: Yes that is also possible @SBK ... MySQL supports `INSERT INTO table (<columns>) SELECT (<columns>)  WHERE id = 3 AND
          NOT EXISTS (....)`  syntax.

Comment: Where would I write the values that I want to insert though. Eg. if I wanted to insert a title and a path into a table, but only is the path-column didn't already contain the path that I want to insert.

Comment: @SBK . . . In Raymond's example, those would be the columns that you select.

Comment: I don't think I'm quite getting it. I've tried this:  `INSERT INTO user2table (title, projectpath) SELECT ("Title", "user1project4") WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user2table WHERE projectpath = 'user1project4')`  However I'm getting an error that `Operand should contain 1 column(s).` Where am I going wrong? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @SBK . . . Remove the parentheses.  You might also need `from dual` -- just don't remember off-hand if MySQL allows a `where` with no `from`.

Comment: Alright great, removing the parentheses solved it. GordonLinoff and @RaymondNijland Thanks a lot both for helping out!

Comment: What about "TABLE_SCHEMA" for the database name?